# Retrieve an aggregated SQL value from a ResultSet in Java

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I've been stuck with this problem for several hours: there are 3 tables, one of them connects the others through a place number and the tray ID. To find out how many samples are on a specific tray I aggregated the places by the tray ID, which works perfectly in pure SQL Code.

My Java code:

```
 ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT TRAYID, COUNT(PlaceNo) AS OCCUPIED " +
                                                "FROM PLACE " +
                                                "GROUP BY TRAYID " +
                                                "HAVING TRAYID = ?");

        ps.setInt(1, trayId);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) { throw new CoolingSystemException(); }

        else {

            spaceOccupied = rs.getInt("OCCUPIED");
```

And with the last line the program crashes. I have also tried `getInt(1)` instead of the name but nothing works. And if the result set would be empty it would crash at

```
if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) { throw new CoolingSystemException(); }
```

What I know for sure is that there is a value

[Image: DBeaver using the same TrayID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi4Ct.png)

I am sure that it is this spot because I logged it at each imaginable point before and after each line.

Does anyone has an idea how to solve it? I also tried every datatype in the get...() function :(

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: You're not calling `rs.next()` anywhere. The idiomatic way to consume result sets is to do it in a `while (rs.next())` loop.

Comment: Damn it... thanks very much that next call breaks my neck the third time already. Just keep forgetting it -.-

Comment: @Philipp, in the question you just deleted, I posted an answer that may work for you. It may be a better way to build your nav bar. Just FYI.

Comment: @Michael_B, thank you a lot for the detailed answer! I partially implemented it in my site and it works very good. I have deleted the post because basically I made a very dump mistake and after correcting it, everything worked fine, but thanks anyway, I implemented it now with nav tags :)

Comment: Your query could be simplified to `SELECT COUNT(PlaceNo) AS OCCUPIED FROM PLACE WHERE TRAYID = ?`. No need for `GROUP BY` when you're only interested in one value of `TRAYID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that after you check whether there is any data in the result set, you're not moving the cursor forward with `rs.next()` before calling `rs.getInt()`. Now as it seems that you're only ever expecting the result set to contain up to one row, you can do the following instead:

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT TRAYID, COUNT(PlaceNo) AS OCCUPIED " +
                                            "FROM PLACE " +
                                            "GROUP BY TRAYID " +
                                            "HAVING TRAYID = ?");

ps.setInt(1, trayId);
rs = ps.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
    spaceOccupied = rs.getInt("OCCUPIED");
} else {
    throw new CoolingSystemException();
}
```

The first invocation of `rs.next()` will return a falsey if the query didn't return any data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Forget this thing about next everytime. Not its working like its supposed to be :)